# How to reuse Icon set with an Expo and Next.js monorepo?

Tags: next.js, expo, icons, monorepo

I'm working on a monorepo project with Expo and Next.js, the code is already sharable, but I want to add icons and make it work for both of them while I use the icon set in the shared ui components. I tried downloading Phosphor icons and create an icon set with 'createIconSetFromIcoMoon' with @expo/vector-icons, but it did not work. I think I have to configure the mobile and the web project, but I'm having a hard time trying to understand what is going on. I just want to know if I'm in the right path, and if I'm, what am I missing, but if you have other approach in this regard, please let me know.

I also do not want to use solito or capacitor for now, I just want to learn how to do a monorepo project.

Here is the code to make the Icon component

```
import { styled } from 'nativewind';
import { createIconSetFromIcoMoon } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import PhosphorIcoMoonConfig from '../icons/phosphor/selection.json';

const PhosphorPhosphorIconSet = createIconSetFromIcoMoon(
  PhosphorIcoMoonConfig,
  'Phosphor',
  'Phosphor.ttf'
);

export const Icon = styled(PhosphorPhosphorIconSet);
```

This are the files that I've extracted from Phosphor downloaded icons:

[Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPPic.png)